# JavaScript insert into Array at index

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I know how to insert into array at index, when that index is already present. Say `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `arr.splice(2, 0, 0)` will result in `[1, 2, 0, 3, 4]`. However I have an empty array which is getting filled from an object which is not in any particular order. Actually array is used to sort the object:

```
var key  = parseInt(object[object_key].timestamp);
while (key && array_sorted[key]) { //Attempt at preventing overwriting elements with same timestamp
    key++;
}
key = key ? key : array_sorted.length + 1;
array_sorted.splice(key, 0, object[object_key].data);
```

Now this will build an array `[object[0].timestamp, object[1].timestamp, object[2].timestamp, ...]` instead of something like this `[undefined, ..., undefined, object[4].timestamp, object[3].timestamp, undefined, object[0].timestamp, undefined, ..., undefined, object[1].timestamp]`... How can I achieve sorting of an object of objects by `timestamp` (object's object's property) using this method? Is there a way to insert at index of an empty array?

Comment: `var a = []; a.splice(2, 0, 'test');` works if you want to insert at the start of the array or index 2. Otherwise wouldn't `a[2] = 'test'` work for you

Comment: @megawac `a.length` returns **1** instead of 3 a[2] will create object with empty array and element with key "2"...

Comment: Are trying to index these with the timestamp as a key? Because your `array_sorted.length` property (fed to the key when the key doesn't validate) could override potential keys...

Comment: @shennan `console.log(key)` before `.splice()` and it returns correct key. When I `.log(array_sorted)` I get regular array without any "undefined" instances...

Comment: I' afraid JS doesn't have array like PHP.

Comment: Why don't you just push them all into an array and do a sort on the Array? Probably easier that writing your own sorting code.

Comment: @lombausch is there an alternative to do the same thing? Should I create array of objects (`{timestamp, object_key}`), sort that, iterate over it and create new array with `.push(object[object_key])`?

Comment: @epascarello the only way to sort an object of objects is with the help of an array. It is the fastest way to do it, since I later need an array of `object[object_key].data` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the actual question, Objects in Javascript do not guarantee any order.

To get the kind of order-based behaviour that you want out of your `object of objects`, you really need to convert it into an `array of objects`. You can then sort it with the `sort` method as per Anand's suggestion.

Or you could sort them as you go:

```
var objects = {
  1:{timestamp:"12345"},
  2:{timestamp:"34567"},
  3:{timestamp:"23456"}
}

var array = [];

for(var i in objects){

  var timestamp = parseInt(objects[i].timestamp);

  var added = false;

  for(var j in array){

    if(timestamp > parseInt(array[j].timestamp)){

      array.splice(j + 1, 0, objects[i]);

      added = true;

      break;

    }
  }

  if (!added) {

    array.unshift(objects[i]);

  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks. I've added a check `added`, that will make sure that if all of the keys are bigger than the one to get added, it will still be inserted.

Comment: @Xeos as you were adding that edit I was also noticing the bug and writing it up. I even used the same `added` variable name :-). Have edited further as we no longer need the check on the variable length. If the item hasn't been added, that will catch it. Also, using `unshift` feels more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going specific but the given example below could help you to solve your problem.

lets say we have

```
var objArray=[{"Name":"Anand"},{"Name":"Jhon"},{"Name":"Paul"}];
```

now you can sort like

```
objArray.sort(function(a, b) {

         var textA = a.Name.toUpperCase();
         var textB = b.Name.toUpperCase():;

         return (textA < textB) ? 1 : (textA > textB) ? -1 : 0;
         //return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0; //for ascending.

  });
```

now you will find sorted array.

Comment: I am just explaining some sort of logical approach in common not for the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understood correctly your question. Actually there are several question's as I can see and I'll try to answer them:

**Sort Object**

You can't sort the object, but you can make an array containing object's properties keys or values sorted by some criteria.

```
var object = {
  a: {
    timestamp: 1385127590866
  },
  c: {
    timestamp: 1385127590872
  },
  b: {
    timestamp: 1385127590877
  }
},

keys = Object.keys(object), // Get object properties as array

sortedByKeys = keys.sort(function(key0, key1) { // ['a', 'b', 'c']
    if(key0 < key1) return -1;
    if(key1 > key0) return 1;
    return 0;
}),

sortedByTimestamp = keys.sort(function(key0, key1) { // ['a', 'c', 'b']
    return object[key1] - object[key0];
}),

sortedValues = [], i, j;
for(i=0, l=sortedByTimestamp.length; i<l; i++) { // [{timestamp:1385127590866}, {timestamp:1385127590872}, {timestamp:1385127590877}]
    sortedValues.push(object[sortedByTimestamp[i]]);
}
```

**Create empty array an place item at specific index**

```
var array = Array(Object.keys().length); // [undefined, undefined, undefined]
array[1] = object['a']; // [undefined, {timestamp:1385127590866}, undefined]
```

Hope it will help.